# Ruby: including a hash inside another hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I have the following hash:

```
EMAIL_PWD_HASH = Hash.new
EMAIL_PWD_HASH[ "email" ] =  { "label" => EMAIL_STR, "type" => "email_field" }
EMAIL_PWD_HASH[ "password" ] = { "label" => PWD_STR, "type" => "password_field" }
```

and the following hash:

```
NEW_USER_HASH = Hash.new
NEW_USER_HASH[ "first" ] = { "label" => FIRST_STR, "type" => "text_field" }
NEW_USER_HASH[ "last" ] =  { "label" => LAST_STR, "type" => "text_field" }

NEW_USER_HASH[ "title" ] =  { "label" => TITLE_STR, "type" => "text_field" }
NEW_USER_HASH[ "bio" ] =  { "label" => BIO_STR, "type" => "text_field" }
```

I would like to add email and password to NEW_USER_HASH after last and before bio. What is the syntax for adding EMAIL_PWD_HASH (the order is important)?

Comment: What do you want to do, that the order is important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NEW_USER_HASH.merge!(EMAIL_PAD_HASH)
```

Note also that hashes in ruby are not ordered.

Comment: @DaveNewton: They are order-preserving, but they still don't support ordering well, and it's generally agreed to be a bad idea to rely on ordering in a hash.

Comment: I am not going to be re-ordering, but I am assuming that they are order-preserving. This would be used (as an example), inside a form.

Comment: @Chuck As of Ruby 1.9, you *can* rely on ordering. The alternative is to re-implement existing functionality, because there are most certainly use-cases where insertion order matters. They support the ordering they support just fine--just not other ordering, or re-ordering.

Comment: @Doug R: He said that he wanted to *add email and password to NEW_USER_HASH after last and before bio*.

Comment: When I added it, it did preserve the order of what was before the insertion point, and what followed it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do what you asked, and I doubt it's possible, but here's a *quick and dirty* way to do what you need:

```
NEW_USER_HASH['email']    = EMAIL_PWD_HASH['email']
NEW_USER_HASH['password'] = EMAIL_PWD_HASH['password']
NEW_USER_HASH['bio']      = NEW_USER_HASH.delete('bio')  # deletes bio and reinsert in the end
```

`email` and `password` are now after `last` and before `bio`, as you asked. :)